# What do you mean by non cellular matrix

Tags: cell-biology, tissue

What do you mean by the non cellular matrix in which connective tissues are embedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [extracellular matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extracellular_matrix):

> In biology, the extracellular matrix (ECM) is a collection of extracellular molecules secreted by cells that provides structural and biochemical support to the surrounding cells.

Its main component are fibers, that can be strongly interlaced as in the case of the [dense connective tissue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_connective_tissue) or more loosely distributed as in the [loose one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_connective_tissue).